# Getting error Please verify that the structure and data types in the DataFrame match the schema of the destination table when appending

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I am running a loop that will run some process create a dataframe and the dataframe is then added to big query table. But when i am appending on existing table I am getting a error. 
Please verify that the structure and data types in the DataFrame match the schema of the destination table.
The values are coming from functions.

```
from  pandas.io import gbq
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from datalab.context import Context
import time

for id_name in ID_:
      df= ['id_recip','length_data','length_action', 'daily_mail_freq', 'weekly_mail_frequency', 'imp_hour', 'imp_day']
      columns = list(df)
      data=[]
      values = [id_name,length_data,length_action, daily_mail, weekly_mail, imp_hour, imp_day]
      zipped = zip(columns, values)
      a_dictionary = dict(zipped)
      print(a_dictionary)
      final_output=pd.DataFrame(a_dictionary)
      final_output = final_output.astype(str)
      final_output.info()
      final_output.to_gbq('internal.frequency_output3',
                            Context.default().project_id,
                            if_exists='append')
```

I converted all data in dataframe to string to avoid datatype mismatch. On first loop table is getting created if it dont exist.

```
Structure in bigquery table  
daily_mail_freq STRING NULLABLE 
id_recip STRING  NULLABLE 
imp_day STRING NULLABLE 
imp_hour  STRING NULLABLE
length_action  STRING NULLABLE 
length_data STRING  NULLABLE
weekly_mail_frequency STRING  NULLABLE
```

There are no dates in them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is using 
google.cloud bigquery. in this case it changes to a sql statement and push data rather than using dataframe.

```
def export_items_to_bigquery(daily_mail_freq,id_recip,imp_day,imp_hour,length_action,length_data,weekly_mail_frequency ):
    # Instantiates a client
    client = bigquery.Client()
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

    # Prepares a reference to the dataset
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('dbn')

    table_ref = dataset_ref.table('fqo')
    table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)  

    rows_to_insert = [
        (daily_mail_freq , id_recip, imp_day, imp_hour, length_action , length_data, weekly_mail_frequency)]
    errors = bigquery_client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # API request
    assert errors == []
```

now in loop just pass the data to the function